# Powerpoint remove style tips next to slide

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint

I'm using a corporate powerpoint template (custom built for the company I work for), and on every slide there are lots of tips displayed next to the slides. These are general styling tips to make sure everyone is using the same consistent styling across presentations.

I would like to remove these tips for a presentation, because it distracts me.

I was able to remove most tips when going to `View > Master Views > Slide Master` and removing the tips by clicking on them and pressing delete, but there are a couple of tips left that I cannot remove this way. For example:

[image: slide example]

How do I get rid of (or toggle on/off) these tips on all slides?

Comment: Please check if [Why can't I select and change the text in the footer?](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/why-can-t-i-select-and-change-the-text-in-the-footer-e8db8184-b244-4370-9d16-c2ec5a33a8a2) helps.

Comment: When you choose View | Slide Master, it takes you to the layout that the current slide is based on. The layout may also be inheriting shapes from the main master that it's based on; after removing the shapes from the layout, scroll up to the slide that the layout is indented under and check for add'l shapes there.